# Running a query on two DBcontext

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, dbcontext

I am trying to run a query against two context and I get this error everytime:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'CC_Metrics_Apps.RefQutReturns'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I am attempting to query like so:

```
Public Function IDQ() As List(Of RefQutReturns)
  Dim val As List(Of RefQutReturns) = (From x In GlobalVar.db.RET.RefQutReturns
                                       Select x).ToList
  Return val
End Function

Public Function QueTypeDD() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
  Dim val As New List(Of SelectListItem)
  Dim valQ = From v In GlobalVar.db.PS.TaskQueueTypes
             Join x In IDQ() On v.QutID Equals x.QutID.ToString
             Select v
  val.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Select Item", .Value = 0})
  For Each v In valQ
    val.Add(New SelectListItem() With {.Text = v.QutDesc, .Value = v.QutID})
  Next
  Return val
End Function
```

Comment: Because of `.ToList()` in the `IDQ()` method you are trying to join a collection of results already materialized on the client with results from the `GlobalVar.db.PS.TaskQueueTypes` on the server side. EF does not support mixing-in local non-primitive types with (SQL) queries evaluated in the database.

Comment: @Pawel so I need to put both queries into memory before running the Join query?

Comment: in your case you have got materialized returns from one context which you are trying to use as an argument for a database query (so you mix Linq to Objects and Linq to Entities) which is not supported. You have 2 contexts - the assumption (which is valid in majority of cases) is that different contexts means different databases and therefore EF won't be possible to create a single query that can join results. The question is why do you have 2 contexts - if they both are working on the same database - can be they merged? If not - you will need to bring results to the client.

Comment: @Pawel can you convert your comment to an answer so I can give you a check mark please.  The issue was resolved by putting both queries into memory and then joining them as you suggested.  However the .tolist was still required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does not support queries spanning more than one context. In majority of cases it may not be possible to create and run a query like this in one database since it will have to access a different database (tracking entities would probably would also be problematic). If you have two contexts but work on one database you may want to merge the contexts. Otherwise you need to bring results for both contexts to the client and combine them using Linq To Objects query. 
Also note that in your case you are mixing Linq To Object query (because of `.ToList()` in the `IDQ()`) with Linq To Entities - this is also not supported since EF does not know how to bring the materialized non-primitive results to the database where the query will be executed.